# Deploying Pytorch Models into Production

Tags: python, reactjs, deep-learning, pytorch, onnx

is it possible for me to create a website that uses ONNX.js to serve the model and create a frontend using React? If yes, please point toward some resources.

Also, what other ways can a Pytorch model be served into production in conjunction with a react frontend, any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have done my final year Engineering project using FastAi and PyTorch and I created a website for deployment using Flask Framework. It was straightforward and simple to create. I suggest looking into this and as for deployment, you can use Heroku or GitHub pages for deploying your model.

You can refer to this https://medium.com/unpackai/how-to-deploy-fast-ai-models-8704ea711ad2

You can also create a notebook app if you are using Jupyter Notebooks. For reference https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/10/develop-and-deploy-an-image-classifier-app-using-fastai/

It was not easy to understand in the beginning but by watching various YouTube videos, I was able to successfully deploy my model online for anyone to use.